# Strange maths coincidence $(6\times 9)+(6+9)=69?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Is this a freak coincidence in maths or there are more of this type of maths calculation?**

$$\color{red}{(6\times 9)}+\color{blue}{(6+9)}=69$$

I try to find more, but I can't. Can you?

Comment: Amazing answers, thank you ALL! wow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply rewrite it as:

$$ab+a+b=10a+b$$
$$ab=9a$$

One can see now, that $b=9$ and $a$ can be anynumber such that $0 \leq a \leq 9$.

Answer (score 3):

$$(6 \times 9) + (6 + 9) = 10 \times 6 + 9 = 69$$

Similarly,
$$(n \times 9) + (n + 9) = 10 \times n + 9 = \text{"}n9\text{''},$$
for any one-digit number $n$

Answer (score 1):

For base $r,$

$$ab+a+b=ra+b\iff b=r-1$$ for $a\ne0$